# Can E[X|Y] be computed from E[X|Y,Z]?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let X, Y and Z be 3 discrete random variables. Is the following true?

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty P\{Y=i\} E[X|Y=i,Z] = E[X|Z]$

Comment: $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Z=z]=\sum_x x\,\mathrm{Pr}(X=x\mid Z=z)=\sum_{x,y} x\,\mathrm{Pr}(X=x\mid Y=y,Z=z)\mathrm{Pr}(Y=y\mid Z=z)=\sum_y \mathrm{E}[X\mid Y=y,Z=z]\,\mathrm{Pr}(Y=y\mid Z=z)$  .

Comment: In terms of random variables, since $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Z]=g(Z)$, $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Y,Z]=h(Y,Z)$, and $\mathrm{Pr}(Y=y\mid Z)=u_y(Z)$, we have $g(Z)=\sum_y h(y,Z)\,u_y(Z)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula is wrong (in general), but the answer to the question in title is true.

Let
$$
X = Y + Z \\ Y = 2Z \\ Z \sim \text{Uniform} \{1, 2, 3\}
$$

Hence $ Y \sim \text{Uniform} \{2, 4, 6\}$

Then, obviously,

$$
E[X | Y, Z] = 3 Z
$$

Whereas

$$
\sum_{y} P(Y = y) E[X | Y=y, Z=z]
= \sum_{y} P(Y = y) E[y + z | Y=y, Z=z]
= \sum_{y} P(Y = y) (y + z)
= E[y] + z = z + 4
$$

Which is wrong for $Z=1$, for example.

So, what's the problem with your formula? The problem is that in your summation you use unconditioned probability over $Y$. Indeed,

$$
\sum_{y} P(Y = y|Z=z) E[X | Y=y, Z=z] 
\\= \sum_{y} \sum_{x} x \overbrace{P(Y = y | Z=z) P(X = x | Y=y, Z=z)}^{P(X=x, Y=y|Z=z)}
\\= \sum_{x,y} x P(X=x, Y=y | Z=z) = E[X|Z=z]
$$

The overbrace equality holds because of [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_%28probability%29):

$$
P(X, Y | Z) = P(X|Y,Z) P(Y|Z)
$$

P.S. Actually, your formula is right iff $Y$ and $Z$ are independent r.v.